# c# Test if list of potential objects contains string

Tags: c#

So I'm brand new to c# and coding in general, so I hope my question even makes sense. I've found similar questions online, but my problem is very specific. So first I have an object class named "Enemy" with a bunch of properties in it.

```
public class Enemy
{
    public string EName { get; set; }
    public int EHealth { get; set; }
    public int EStamina { get; set; }
    public int EPower { get; set; }

    public Enemy(string ename, int ehealth, int estamina, int epower)
    {
        EName = ename;
        EHealth = ehealth;
        EStamina = estamina;
        EPower = epower;
    }
}
```

Then in my main, I made a list for new "Enemy" objects to be added to:

```
List<Enemy> Enemies = new List<Enemy>();
```

I have a random number between 1 and 4 that determines how many enemies will be spawned, called "eNumber":

```
for (int i = 1; i <= eNumber; i++)
        {
            var rndmHealth = rndm.Next(6, 12);
            var rndmStamina = rndm.Next(6, 12);
            var rndmPower = rndm.Next(6, 12);
            var enemy = new Enemy($"Goblin{i}", rndmHealth, rndmStamina, rndmPower);
            Console.WriteLine($@"
{enemy.EName}:
Health:  {enemy.EHealth}
Stamina: {enemy.EStamina}
Power:   {enemy.EPower}
");
        }
```

So this should make a random number of enemies spawn (in this case, "goblins"), along with random ints for their properties. The console  should then tell the player the names of the enemies and their properties. I now want the player to be able to type in the name of the monster that he wants to attack, so like "Goblin1" or "Goblin3", but I want the player to be prompted to try again if an invalid EName is entered. I hope this makes sense, thanks for your time!

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

OK, I've almost figured this out!
I replaced

```
var enemy = new Enemy($"Goblin{i}", rndmHealth, rndmStamina, rndmPower);
```

with

```
Enemies.Add(new Enemy($"Goblin{i}", rndmHealth, rndmStamina, rndmPower));
```

Now, on creation, new Enemy Objects are added to the Enemies list. However, now I don't know how to access their properties:

```
Console.Writeline(enemy.EName);
```

^This no longer works. All I need to know now is the correct syntax for this and I'm set :]
Thank you to everyone who's been trying to help me!

Comment: The player doesn't seem to be entering anything at all. Did you post the right code?

Comment: I can´t see anything where payer enters anything at all.

Comment: Where does the user enter the name of the monster? You might want something like Console.ReadKey() for users to allow input, and set that to a variable so you can use it to compare to your existing list. Something like:
`var userInput = Console.ReadKey();
if (userInput == {some compare value})
{
     do something;
}
else
{
     do something else;
}
Since Console.ReadKey() only allows one character, you can use a list for them to choose from: 1. Goblin1, 2. Goblin2, 3. Goblin3.. Please enter a number... Something along those lines.

Comment: Your loop creates Enemies then it prints out their stats that's all, You Enemies Lists is never being used, i don't understand

Comment: Is `rndm.Next(6, 12)` meant to be the rolling of two dice?

Comment: Just a hint too - in `Enemy` you should override `.ToString()` to produce your console dump of your enemy. Then you can write `Console.WriteLine(enemy.ToString())`. Makes your code a bit cleaner.

Comment: How is this question about "Test if list of potential objects contains string
"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
        List<Enemy> Enemies = new List<Enemy>();// Declare your list

        // Loop To populate the list 
        for (int i = 1; i <= eNumber; i++)
        {
          Enemies.Add(new Enemy($"Goblin{i}", rndm.Next(6, 12), rndm.Next(6, 12), rndm.Next(6, 12)));
        }
        // Loop Throught The Enemies, Then you can access their status 
        for (int i = 0; i < Enemies.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Enemies[i].EName,Enemies[i].EHealth,Enemies[i].EStamina,Enemies[i].EPower);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Now I don't know why, but the Console.Writeline would only write EName, so I tried Console.Writline($"{Enemies[i].EName}, etc etc") and that made it work completely.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is here
for (int i = 0; i <= Enemies.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Enemies[i].EType.Contains(ATattack))

it should be `i < Enemies.Count` since the index is zero based

Enjoy

Comment: Thanks, this does make the error go away, but whether or not I type in a valid answer, I get the "Invalid answer; try again" and then the loop doesn't even happen, I just get a "press any key to continue..."

Comment: @PineappleSurprise checkout my comment and give that a try. Also you can use a while loop to continue comparing the user data.